# Can I validate a file's size with flash and still normally upload it?

Tags: javascript, flash, file-upload

Imagine you have a form that allows file upload. The file's size is limited to X MB. When we want to validate the file's size, we run into problems with Internet Explorer and it's security features.

We thought Flash might be a solution, and we'd like to check a file's size using it, and, if it passes our validation, allow it to be submitted along with the rest of the form. The thing is, all of the code snippets that use Flash to perform file validation, are using Flash to post the file upload. I'd like to be able to post the entire form at once, since my object depends on all of the params being received at once.

A colleague of mine said the above scenario should be possible, but I think it's not. Are there other alternatives, or is creating/handling the post using entirely Flash the only one?

Comment: You'll have to let Flash handle the file selection process, and hence the upload -- but, you can always tell Flash all your other POST parameters so that you're still uploading once from one place. The server won't know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. I've recently made a flash file that does sort of that. Basically it inspects a loaded swf for framerate, filesize, actionscript version and a bunch of other stuff and then outputs it via external interface to javascript.

It did however feel a bit hacky with a lot of steps and asynchronous calls.

Of course first you have to create the flash file which will inspect the file. I don't have the one I made since I'm at home and really should be in bed :) Also your solution will be pretty different but if you want I can post it tomorrow.(Or later today really)

To create the flash you will need ExternalInterface. It is possible to add a callback so you can call a function inside the flash via javascript. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Then embed the flash file somewhere on your page. It cannot be inside a hidden div if I remember correctly.

Create a javascript function on the page that the swf can call once it has the filesize.

Call the relevent function(with the file url) inside the swf when you want to check the filesize.

The function inside the swf should load the file and will then be able to output the filesize to the javascript function.

Comment: Ok, but to post everything at once, the file should be loaded in the file field as a normal uploaded file, and not uploaded to Flash, right? From there, somehow, Flash should access it and report if the filesize's too big.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. Since the file is a local one? you would have to use filereference http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Unfortunately filereference requires userinput to work so it's not really a good solution.

Comment: Perhaps this could work:
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html

Comment: We tried ActiveX but MS released some update and it no longer works for us.

Comment: Sure, but, coming back to the initial question, what I asked for is not possible, right?